# mvc pattern gui actionlistener class

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am working a basic mvc pattern with gui. This code includes JComboBox. When click on jcombobox and selecting a string item from here empty label will fill a specific string. How should ı do my controller Class ?

This is my Gui class

```
public class SchoolView extends JPanel {
    private JTextField selectedStandName;
    private JComboBox<String> stands;
    private JLabel standLabel;
    String[] items = { "Rainbow Pots", "BookWorm's Place","Caffein Charger","Jedi's Place"};

    public SchoolView() {
        stands = new JComboBox<String>(items);
        add(stands);
        addStandLabel();
        addStandInfoLabel();
        addStandInfoField();
    }

    private void addStandLabel() {
        standLabel = new JLabel("Stands");
        add(standLabel);
    }

    private void addStandInfoLabel() {
        JLabel selectedStandInfo = new JLabel("Stand Info");
        add(selectedStandInfo);
    }
    private void addStandInfoField() {
        SelectedStandName = new JTextField();
        add(selectedStandName);
        selectedStandName.setColumns(20);
    }
}
```

This is my controller class

```
public class SchoolController {
    public SchoolController(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the [MVC relationship](https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC690874.png):
View reacts to model updates (Observer pattern)
Controller reacts to View (observer pattern)
Controller updated Model

Then your controller will subscribe itself to the SchoolView and on the event will update the second view component.
See pseudo-code below:

```
public class SchoolController implements OnSelectListener {
    JTextField viewComponent;
    public SchoolController(schoolView, viewComponent){
        schoolView.onSelect(this)
        this.viewComponent= viewComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelect(selectedItem) {
        viewComponent.set(selectedItem);
    }
}
```